# WCF, Ninject, and life cycle

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm adding Ninject to my WCF service (hosted in IIS).  I intend for the WCF service to automatically instantiate instances of my NHibernate repository classes.

I originally used Castle (and later Ninject) to instantiate those objects in my ASP.NET MVC client and pass them to a service class.  In this case, the scope was PerWebRequest (Castle) or InRequestScope (Ninject).  The NHibernate session would be implicitly created along with a transaction that would be committed when the repositories were disposed.

I would like to keep this same approach by having the client implicitly control the lifetime of the session/transaction by newing/closing the service.

Would one of the existing Ninject scope methods work in this manner (InThreadScope or InRequestScope perhaps)?  Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

I would let the client *explicitly* control the lifetime of those kind of objects. Don't inject such an object, but inject a factory that can create such an object for you. This follows the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517006/ninject-caching-an-injected-datacontext-lifecycle-management/4518052#4518052) for more information.